# how to htaccess rewrite and url with whitespace?

Tags: .htaccess, magento, url-rewriting

I am trying to write a htaccess redirect for a url from the old site to the new website
the old url has whitespace in the url link,
I tried

```
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/office%20coffee/officecoffee.html [NC]
RewriteRule (.*)  /coffee/portion-packs.html  [R=301,NC,L]
```

but it doesnot redirect, what would be a solution to this.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanking you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your 2 line with this one:

```
RewriteRule "^office coffee/officecoffee.html$" /coffee/portion-packs.html  [R=301,NC,L]
```